# How to connect Google Analytics to Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony

I have a small blog on Symfony 4. I need to add views to the articles. Decided to use Google Analytics. But I did not find the normal documentation how to connect Google Analytics to the symfony 4.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you simply have to append a script tag that is provided in Google Analytics' web interface. See either [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) or [this answer on the help resource](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080). Perhaps, that would be the best option for you, since you just have a simple blog. The script should probably be added in your base template, or the layout so that it renders just above the closing `</body>` tag.

Another option would be setting up a server-to-server interaction with GA. There are several bundles for that: [one](https://packagist.org/packages/widop/google-analytics-bundle), [two](https://packagist.org/packages/happyr/google-analytics-bundle). But most probably you won't need that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the script in your default base layout like the conventional `base.html.twig`. If you want to minimize the interaction with the layout you can create a Twig function that returns the **Tracking ID** stored in `parameters.yml`, either use bundle that provides extra features for interaction with your server, have a look for [GoogleAnalyticsBundle](https://github.com/Happyr/GoogleAnalyticsBundle) which is still maintained by a symfony core developer.